# GNU Autotools: rebuild without version info

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I need to build a lib that is configured with autotools. The usual `configure && make && make install` steps produce versioned shared lib, something like `libfoo.so.x.x` Is it possible to modify configure.ac or Makefile.am (and of course follow up with autoreconf ) so that un-versioned lib is build.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, assuming that the library is built with `libtool`, you can remove the version information by adding the `-avoid-version` flag to the library's LDFLAGS.

For example, if before there was
`libfoo_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 1:0` you would change it to `libfoo_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version`. After this, you'd regenerate and rerun configure (autoreconf -vfi && ./configure) and rebuild.

Simply removing `-version-info ...` isn't sufficient, since libtool will then generate a library with version info 0.0.0.

See the libtool manual for more information: http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Link-mode.html